# d3.js - Using geo.tiles and behavior.zoom without cartographic projection

Tags: javascript, d3.js, svg

I have a big "map" with 18 levels of zoom. I have one tile at level 0, and 2^17 x 2^17 tiles at level 17 (the tiles are 256x256 pixels). And they are accessible via the `/tiles/z/y/x` schema.

It's not a cartographic or real map, it's more like a very big image. What I want it's more like [Zoomify](http://www.zoomify.com/) or [PanoJS](http://www.dimin.net/software/panojs/) than a real map. But I want to add extra functionality at the level 17.

I tried to adapt [this](http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/4132797) code but I have no idea of how configure the different parameters, the function for `d3.geo.tile`, or why I need a projection (I don't have spherical coordinates). That example code *almost* do the work for me, but I can not navigate to level 17 or level 0 (where should be only one tile).

How should I fix that example to work as I need? Is there an example to do what I want with d3.js (zoomable images, no maps)? And as a bonus: How can I extend geo.tiles to add a slightly different behavior at the last level of zoom? In particular I want to load SVG images for each tile when `zoom > 17`. Those SVG are also accessible via `/tiles/17/y/x/svg`.

Comment: Is there maybe the example you are working on online. And could you create a picture at the last zooming step with the svgs? Thank you.

Comment: Hi @kwoxer the code I'm using is exactly like this: http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/4132797

But I haven't anything online at the moment.